# Replace Characters in a string except values inside double quote

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to replace an array of characters with empty space except values inside double quote in a string.

**Example**

```
"India & China" relationship & future development
```

In the above example, I need to replace `&` but thats not inside any of the double quotes(`""`). The expected result should be

**Result**

```
"India & China" relationship  future development
```

**Other Examples of String**

```
relationship & future development "India & China" // Output: relationship  future development "India & China"

"relationship & future development India & China // Output: reflect the same input string as result string when the double quote is unclosed.
```

I have so far done the below logic to replace the characters in a string.

**Code**

```
string invalidchars = "()*&;<>";
Regex rx = new Regex("[" + invalidchars + "]", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
string srctxtaftrep = rx.Replace(InvalidTxt, " ");

RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", options);
srctxtaftrep = regex.Replace(srctxtaftrep, @" ");
InvalidTxt = srctxtaftrep;
```

Comment: Have your string fixed structure as in example, i.e., from the start is text inside double quote then other text?

Comment: No. The string format may vary in different inputs.

Comment: You could iterate over the characters of the string, incrementing the count of double quote characters as you go along. Then if the count of double quote characters is odd (using mod), replace an invalid character

Comment: What's with input like: `"India & China" relationship ""&"" future development`? Is the `&` inside or outside of the quotes?

Comment: For this input: `"India & China" relationship ""&"" future development`, the `&` is outside and can be replaced.

Comment: @Deva: then my non-regex approach below should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a non-regex approach using a `StringBuilder` which should work:

```
string input = "\"India & China\" relationship & future development";
HashSet<char> invalidchars = new HashSet<char>("()*&;<>");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool inQuotes = false;
foreach(char c in input)
{
    if(c == '"') inQuotes = !inQuotes;
    if ((inQuotes && c != '"') || !invalidchars.Contains(c))
        sb.Append(c);
}
string output = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: @deva: what .NET version are you using? Maybe you need `new HashSet<char>(input.ToCharArray())`

Comment: Using .NET 4.0 version.

Comment: @Deva: I'm also using .NET 4. However, you can also use the string alone and the code works as it is. A `HashSet` is just more efficient, all the more if the list of invalid chars gets longer and/or the text is long. Btw, it works even on Mono which uses .NET 3.5, have a look: http://ideone.com/TA4oRS

Comment: OK. But, The code doesnt replace `"` when the replace character includes `"`. Example like this: `()*&;<>"`.

Comment: @Deva: Ok, i've overlooked that. But you need to provide better samples which include this case. What should happen if there are multiple `"`, what is the quoting character that should remain and what are the invalid characters? You can include it with: `new HashSet<char>("()*&;<>\"");`

Comment: @Deva: However, i have edited the answer to support also `"` as invalid char.